# How can I lower germ levels?

Tags: simcity-2013

The people of my city keep complaining the area is too germy but I have absolutely 0 idea on how to fix this. I haven't made my city too large, everything's pretty small and I have a clinic open with an extra Patient Rooms Wing and ambulance

Comment: if you have nothing to make the germs with, this issue addressed in the 3.0 update.

Answer (score 6):

Make sure pollution from your industrial zones isn't blowing into your city (plant trees in between the residential zones and industrial zones to prevent this.

Make sure garbage isn't left lying around the streets, you can check this on the garbage maps.

Make sure sewage is dealt with adequately, and don't build your sewage pipe near people's homes.

Ensure that your water system is pumping clean water around your city, by using filtration pumps.

Comment: Ensure that your water system is pumping *clean* water around your city, by using filtration pumps.

Comment: Okay so my Industrial Zone is definitely not blowing in Polluted air, so I'll have to check out and see if it's the water or Garbage now.

Comment: You need to look at the pollution data layer. [air] heavy industry creates general pollution in the whole region -- you may be getting hit with another city's output. [ground] specialist industry buildings create a ton of ground pollution; spam trees (see James' tip) [buildings] a http://orcz.com/SimCity:_Wellness_Center will temporarily decontaminate a building and lower the risk of illness.

Comment: Also check the garbage info layer. My university city was having massive air pollution issues w/o any factories or being downwind from a city that did. My garbage collection, however, was solidly yellow/red and it was overflowing everywhere.

Comment: There is also a "Germs" layer that will show you all of the above.  You can find it in the medic pane.

Answer (score 5):

As Xenox mentioned, you need to keep your city clean of pollution from sewage, factories and the garbage your sims will naturally leave behind.

What also helps though is education. Education is an often over looked but hugely helpful way to help manage your Sims. The benefit that you are looking for here is that they will take better care of themselves and overall be healthier. Combine this with keeping your pollutants away from where they live and it will go a long way.

Nothing can really clear up ground/water pollution except for time. You can however plant trees (they are under the $$ wealth parks on the second page) to help with air pollution. The pollution will kill the trees off over time so you will have to replant them from time to time but they do help reduce the sickness caused by air pollution.

Anywho, Hope this helps.

Comment: Education also encourages recycling which (may) decrease the qty of garbage.

Comment: @user43524 That it does... Also educated sims consume less water and power and while I thought this was a small bonus when I put in a university I went from like 15MW free to 140MW, hehe.. Education is really a key to any 10,000+ population city.

Answer (score 2):

There is also an addon for the Hospital Building that clears germs afaik.